# How to create function template signatures?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I have such template functions:

```
template<class R> list<R> f(const boost::function<R()>&);
template<class R, class A0> list<R> f(const boost::function<R(T0)>&, list<A0>);
template<class R, class A0, class A1> list<R> f(const boost::function<R(T0)>&, list<A0>, list<A1>);
```

To run one of them i need to write for example:

```
int one() { return 1; }
int inc(int x) { return x + 1; }

list<int> l;

f<int>(one);
f<int, int>(inc, l);
```

And my goal is to just write:

```
f(one);
f(inc, l);
```

I heard that this is possible by some kind of template signature specialization, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use `boost::function` but function declarations as template arguments so that your compiler knows what you want to do just from the arguments: `template<typename R, typename A0, R (*F)(A0)> list<R> f(F, list<A0>)`  Anyhow, I didn't test that and I'm sure it doesn't work that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without C++11, you can't get away from specifying a return type of a function.

```
template<typename R, typename F>
    R bar(F func) {
        return func();
    }

bar<int>(foo);
```

With the new C++11 features you can though.

```
template<typename F>
    auto baz(F func) -> decltype(func()) {
        return func();
    }

baz(foo);
```

You can template the function/functor as a parameter, instead of trying to specify that it has to be a boost::function.

```
void zero() {cout << "zero" << endl;}
void one(int a) {cout << "one" << endl;}
void two(int a, int b) {cout << "two" << endl;}

template<typename F>
    void f(const F &func) {
        func();
    }

template<typename F, typename T0>
    void f(const F &func, T0 t0) {
        func(t0);
    }

template<typename F, typename T0, typename T1>
    void f(const F &func, T0 t0, T1 t1) {
        func(t0, t1);
    }
```

This lets you pass in the function pointer rather simply.

```
f(zero);
f(one, 1);
f(two, 1, 2);
```

If you need to actually use functions or bind you can pass that in to the same interface.

```
// without specifying the function
f(boost::bind(zero));
f(boost::bind(one, _1), 1);
f(boost::bind(two, _1, _2), 1, 2);

// or by specifying the object
boost::function<void()> f0        = boost::bind(zero);
boost::function<void(int)> f1     = boost::bind(one, _1);
boost::function<void(int,int)> f2 = boost::bind(two, _1, _2);
f(f0);
f(f1, 1);
f(f2, 1, 2);
```

As well as with a functor, which is typical for passing in strict weak ordering behavior to the standard containers.

```
struct zoobies {
    void operator()() const {}
};

f(zoobies());
```

It doesn't have to check the type of what you pass in to it, only that it satisfies the interface.  This is one of the reasons C++ templates are typically much more powerful than generics in other languages.

And for completeness... If you actually did want to restrict it to boost::function, here is an example.

```
template<typename T>
    void p(const boost::function<T> &func) {
        func();
    }

template<typename T, typename A0>
    void p(const boost::function<T> &func, A0 a0) {
        func(a0);
    }


boost::function<void()> f0(zero);
p(f0);

boost::function<void(int)> f1(one, _1);
p(f1, 1);
```

Update:

```
void foo() {cout << "zero" << endl;}
void foo(int a) {cout << "one" << endl;}
void foo(int a, int b) {cout << "two" << endl;}
```

boost::bind works out of the box, with this, although the raw function pointers have more of a problem. foo is ambiguous there.

```
f( (void(*)())        foo      );
f( (void(*)(int))     foo, 1   );
f( (void(*)(int,int)) foo, 1, 2);
```

If you fully specify the function pointer then it works, though that isn't what anyone wants to do.

With boost::bind as evidence, You should be able to determine the arity from the calling convention of `f`.  If I get some time today I'll play with it.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot, but I still have a problem with one more thing. Is it possible to do it like you did it with `zero`, `one` and `two` functions, but when all of these have the same name but different args?

Comment: @vintitres Added a little more information, though incomplete in regards to raw pointers.

Comment: I solved this by creating additional template specializations: `void f(void(*func)())`, `template <typename T0> void f(void(*func)(T0), T0 t0)` and `template <typename T0, typename T1> void f(void(*func)(T0, T1), T0 t0, T1 t1)`. Maybe this isn't clean but works. I believe boost::bind does the same thing, but I'm not sure. Thanks again for your answer it cleared up a lot for me.